# Why style attr change can not trigger rerender in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why the display attr only change once when i click the button, it will not work afterwards

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState(true);
const toggle = () => {
  setIsShow(!isShow);
  console.log(isShow);
}
return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => toggle()}>trigger</button>
    <span style={{display: isShow ? 'static' : 'none'}}>content area</span>
  </div>);
 }
export default App;
```

But,when i add key in the span, it can work. Why?

```
<span key={isShow} style={{display: isShow ? 'static' : 'none'}}>content area</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such property in `display` as `static`. You can either use `block` or `inline` based on your preference.

Here is a working demo: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-mountain-k2w7w6?file=/src/App.js)

As to why adding `key` works, I think the reason is that React use `key` to find changes on the page and re-render it.

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity

Therefore, it might trigger a re-render by its diffing algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `display: static` is an invalid value, change it to something like `block`, or leave it `undefined`

```
<span style={{display: isShow ? undefined : 'none'}}>content area</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "static" is not the legal attribute of display, so when you want to set the attribue from 'none' to 'static' is will not work.

The code below should work fine.

```
<span style={{display: isShow ? 'unset' : 'none'}}>content area</span>
```